# Android studio library dependency not showing up

Tags: java, android

I went  to **file -->app--> dependencies --> green plus sign** and press on **library dependency**. Nothing show up. I trying to add the support v4 dependency so I can extend **Fragment Activity**. Now I having error cannot resolve symbol support.

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ViewPager viewpager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        PagerAdapter padapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewpager.setAdapter(padapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please remove any emoticons and try to minimize your code so the problem still shows. Also state the error message in a clear way (Line, Exception message etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the **build.gradle** file for your application and add this line `compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"`

> Make sure you have downloaded the Android Support Repository using the SDK Manager.

ref [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/tools/support-library/setup.html)

Comment: Happy to hear that :)